Cant see rpm and kmph on python consloe app with obd2
import obd
import time

class DashboardConsole:
    def __init__(self, com_port):
        self.com_port = com_port
        self.connection = None

    def connect(self):
        try:
            print(f"Trying to connect to {self.com_port}...")
            self.connection = obd.Async(self.com_port)
            self.connection.start()
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                print(f"Connected successfully to {self.com_port}")
                return True
            else:
                print(f"Failed to connect to {self.com_port}")
                return False
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to connect to {self.com_port}: {e}")
            return False

    def run(self):
        if not self.connect():
            return
        
        time.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds after connection before querying data
        
        while True:
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                rpm_response = self.connection.query(obd.commands.RPM)
                if rpm_response and rpm_response.value is not None:
                    print(f"RPM: {rpm_response.value}")
                else:
                    print("No RPM data available")

                speed_response = self.connection.query(obd.commands.SPEED)
                if speed_response and speed_response.value is not None:
                    print(f"Speed: {speed_response.value.to('kph')}")
                else:
                    print("No Speed data available")
            else:
                print("Not connected to OBD-II")
            
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    com_port = "COM5"  # Use COM5 for the connection
    app = DashboardConsole(com_port)
    app.run()




Issue Description:
I am developing a Python script to retrieve RPM and Speed data from an OBD-II device using the obd library. Despite successfully connecting to the COM port (COM5 in my case) where the OBD-II device is paired, I am consistently getting "No RPM data available" and "No Speed data available" messages.
Steps Taken:
Connection Establishment: The script successfully connects to the COM port (COM5) using obd.Async.
Data Querying: It queries RPM (obd.commands.RPM) and Speed (obd.commands.SPEED) data within a loop.
Debugging Attempts:
Increased delay (time.sleep(2)) after connection initialization.
Verified that the OBD-II device supports RPM and Speed commands.
Checked vehicle readiness (engine running, vehicle in a state to provide data).
Expected Behavior:
I expect the script to retrieve RPM and Speed data from the connected OBD-II device and print the values in the console.
Actual Behavior:
The script continuously prints "No RPM data available" and "No Speed data available" messages, indicating that it is not receiving valid data despite a successful connection.
Connection Establishment:
Successfully connected to the COM port (COM5) where the OBD-II device is paired using obd.Async.
Data Querying:
Attempted to retrieve RPM data using obd.commands.RPM.
Attempted to retrieve Speed data using obd.commands.SPEED.
Debugging Attempts:
Increased delay (time.sleep(2)) after establishing the connection to allow time for initialization.
Verified that the OBD-II device supports RPM and Speed commands.
Checked the vehicle's readiness (ensured the engine is running or in a state to provide data).
Observations:
Despite a successful connection and these attempts, the script continuously prints "No RPM data available" and "No Speed data available" messages, indicating that valid data is not being received.
